# How can i insert a value into a table when the sysdate is correct

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

How can i insert a value into a table when the sysdate is correct.. This is the code i have but the stat field stays blank

```
begin
  for idx in 1 .. apex_application.g_f01.count
  loop
    if apex_application.g_f01(idx) is not null then
      update outgoing 
      set STAT ='CONFIRM'
   WHERE FILENUMBER = APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(IDX)
   AND DEPARTMENT = apex_application.g_f03(idx)
   and OUTGOINGDATE= sysdate
         ;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you verified that `apex_application.g_f0x` are correct (i.e. represent columns you think they do - if not, use *inspect element* in your browser), then the most suspicious condition is this:

```
and OUTGOINGDATE = sysdate
```

`SYSDATE` is a function that returns both date AND time, e.g.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
29.01.2019 22:02:32

SQL>
```

I doubt that `OUTGOINGDATE` column contains *exactly* current date/time value. One option, which might fix that, is to truncate one or both values, such as

```
and OUTGOINGDATE = trunc(sysdate)
```

or

```
and trunc(OUTGOINGDATE) = trunc(sysdate)
```

as `TRUNC` function *removes* time component, so you'd be comparing dates only. Note that the 2nd option prevents use of index (if it exists) on `OUTGOINGDATE` column; it won't cause problems if table contains not-that-many rows, but might (and probably will) if the table is large. There's a workaround, though - you'd use, for example,

```
and outgoingdate >= trunc(sysdate)
and outgoingdate <  trunc(sysdate + 1)
```

If that's not the case, examine `OUTGOINGDATE` column's values and act accordingly. If you're unsure what to do, provide some more info.